# MutableLiveData with initial value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

How I can initialize **MutableLiveData** with initial value?
I'm looking for something like:

`val text = MutableLiveData<String>("initial value")`

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`MutableLiveData` has been updated and now it has a constructor that accepts an initial value :)

From what I can see, the constructor is available starting from this version:

`implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha01'`

It's a shame they haven't updated `MediatorLiveData` to reflect that, though.

Edit: they finally did it! `MediatorLiveData` has a constructor that accepts an initial value as well starting from [`2.6.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.6.0)!

---

[`2.1.0` is finally stable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/arch#2.1.0), so now you can actually see the new constructor in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#MutableLiveData(T)).

Comment: Is this still correct?  Looking at the docs, I don't see a public constructor that accepts any arguments: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData

Comment: @Noel This change isn't included in the stable version, that's why you don't see it there. If you add the dependency and open the class you'll see the new constructor.

Comment: I don't think this is valid anymore. 2.1.0-alpha01 version for me does not give me another constructor

Comment: @KlitosG. [`2.1.0` is now finally stable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/arch#2.1.0), so you can actually see the constructor in the docs now: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#MutableLiveData(T)

Comment: @FredPorciúncula thanks, you are correct. Some dependency tree problem was making my gradle download version 2.0.0 regardless of me explicitly asking for 2.1.0

Comment: Is there a not-nullable version of `MutableLiveData` with this update?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert Nope, but there's a lint check called `NonNullableMutableLiveData` (it's actually been mentioned in a fix for the [latest release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#version_230_2)), and it's also not really hard to write one yourself:

```
class NonNullableLiveData<T>(initialValue: T) : MutableLiveData<T>(initialValue) {

  override fun getValue(): T = super.getValue()!!
}
```

Answer (score 55):

You can create a handy [Extension Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) that does the initialization for you.

```
fun <T : Any?> MutableLiveData<T>.default(initialValue: T) = apply { setValue(initialValue) }

val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>().default("Initial value!")
```

Comment: You could also create a semi-constructor `fun <T: Any?> MutableLiveData<T>(initialValue: T) = MutableLiveData().apply { postValue(initialValue) }` to make it more convenient (use `setValue` when you are certain this method will only be called from the main thread)

Comment: I was using this extension function for a while and today I changed it to `fun <T : Any?, LD : MutableLiveData<T>> LD.default(initialValue: T) = apply { setValue(initialValue) }` to enable it's use on any class extending `MutableLiveData`, e.g. `MediatorLiveData`.

Answer (score 45):

**UPDATE:**
Nowadays I would use `MutableStateFlow` instead of `MutableLiveData` with initial value.

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow

---

Finally, I realize that I can use

`val text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { postValue("initial value")}`

*(`postValue` is necessary when using from a background thread, otherwise when using from the main thread you can safely use `value = "initial value"`)*

Comment: You can use setValue in a ViewModel.

Comment: This is not the same as setting an initial value.
you can easily create a race condition if you are doing this from a worker thread.
Reading the value right after the postValue(...) is not guaranteed to give you the posted value, since the setValue(...) will run on a different thread

Answer (score 16):

Though this is a Kotlin question, I though it might be helpful if I put the Java version for this as well.

While using `androidx` dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0"
```

Initialize the `MutableLiveData` using the constructor as follows.

```
new MutableLiveData<>("Initial value");
```

While using the `android` dependency:

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1'
```

Initialize as follows.

```
MutableLiveData<String> text = MutableLiveData<String>();
text.setValue("Initial value");
```

The `androidx` dependency does have the constructor that takes a value for the initialization of your `LiveData`. However, if you are using the `android` dependency you will not have that option of doing the initialization using the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension constructor (sugar trick) like this:

```
fun <T : Any?> MutableLiveData(defaultValue: T) = MutableLiveData<T>().apply { setValue(defaultValue) }
```

Using:

```
var defaultValue: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("Default value")
```

Answer (score 2):

Also this way..

```
    val data = MutableLiveData<String>()
    data.value = "data"
    val text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        "apply"
    }
    Log.d("Data",text.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a better solution if you want some default value to be passed in your `MutableLiveData<T>` If you are using kotlin then there is a `class` called `ObservableProperty<T>` which can help you pass the default for your MutableLiveData.Here's my implementation.

```
val nameLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
var name: String by Delegates.observable("") { _, _, newValue ->
    nameLiveData.postValue(newValue)
}
```

In your `Activity` or `Fragment` observe this property.

```
viewModel.nameLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        //Your logic goes here
    })
```

All you have to do change the value is do `name = "Joe"` and it will posted in your LiveData

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
val text by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>("Initial text") }
```

This way, you are using lazy from kotlin and setting the default value. or even shorter like this:

```
val text by lazy { MutableLiveData<>("Initial text") }
```